# Disable flag pop-up message

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags

Can we please have the option to disable the "Thanks for flagging!" pop-up we get every time we flag a comment?

This is the one we get when we flag as No longer needed:

[image: Thanks for flagging pop-up]

The pop-up for an abusive flag is a lot longer:

[image: Thanks for flagging abusive comment pop-up]

We can flag 100 comments a day and I really don't want to see that every single time.

Comment: Well, it must stay there, imho

Comment: adblock should work

Comment: @KevinB Can it work in a way that does not also hide messages such as "you have only N votes left" or "you already voted to delete that post"?

Comment: @KevinB Nope, atleast the one I have doesn't